# Jquery: select all elements except one with specific child with specific attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Assuming I have something like this:

```
<div class="testdiv">
    <a href="/link1">link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="testdiv">
    <a href="/link2">link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="testdiv">
    <a href="/link3">link 3</a>
</div>
<div class="testdiv">
    <a href="/link4">link 4</a>
</div>
```

Now I want select all `<div>`s of class `testdiv` except the `div` that has a child `<a>` with attribute `href="/link3"`, how to do that with jQuery?

I know I can do this:

```
$('div.testdiv')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `:not` + `:has` it can be done easily with one selector:

```
$('div.testdiv:not(:has(a[href="/link3"]))')
```

If you don't quote the value in the attribute ("CSS identifiers") you need to escape the slash(`/`) with two backslashes (`\\`):

```
$('div.testdiv:not(:has(a[href=\\/link3]))')
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pF5y8/)

If There can be only one anchor in a div, you can use this:

```
$('div.testdiv:has(a[href!="\\/link3")')
```

Comment: I like how you wrote your script, but still it selects all the divs without the exception

Comment: @evilReiko. Sorry there was `]` missing... I fixed it and added a demo

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` if you're quoting the attribute.

Comment: @BoltClock. Two reasons **1.** `If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\.` **2.** It doesn't work without it... `:)`

Comment: Pretty sure you only have to do that when you're not quoting the attribute value.

Comment: @BoltClock. You're right, if I use quotes it's not have to be used. I'm going to keep it as it doesn't hurt anything, and because this is no docs they says it's valid without escaping it.

Comment: @gdoron What if the link is a variable? `var link = '/link3'; $('div.testdiv:has(a[href!="\\' + link + '")');` So should I use double slashes or without? It seems like it works even without them!

Comment: @evilReiko. I wouldn't use them if it's a variable, I would add them to the variable value. anyway, as boltclock mentioned, it works without them as well  as long as you use quotes. I would keep them anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock. Can you reference me to the docs about the quotes?

Comment: The [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) mentions the difference between strings (quoted) and identifiers (unquoted). It seems jQuery follows the same set of rules since allowing unquoted attribute selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock. Thanks, I really appreciate it. I edited the answer with that useful info. **thanks**

Comment: @BoltClock. As a mod, answers like _"Ali Tarhini"_ below, should be flagged and deleted or not? In general, answers that are clearly wrong should be flagged? What's benefit of keeping tem live? (I would flag it, but from my experience those flags are declined, suggesting to downvote, but I did that part already... :) )

Comment: @gdoron: Answers that are clearly wrong should **not** be flagged. A wrong answer is still an answer - it's not for a mod to delete. You can always downvote the answer if you think it's wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock. I wish SO will invent a garbage collection for those kind of "answers", they are nothing but noise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for this:

```
var elements = $('.testdiv').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find('a[href=\\/link3]').length;
});
```

Comment: You need to escape the `/` with `\\\`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still selects all divs without exception!

Comment: @evilReiko. Yes, that is because the first argument of `filter` is the index, not the element... see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pF5y8/1/) for how to use `filter`. $Will, fix it and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @gdoron: My bad; I'm not with it today.

Comment: Allow me to improve it a bit.

Comment: @gdoron: Well that's purely stylistic; I prefer to be explicit/type-strict in my boolean checks and parameter declarations.

Comment: Then why didn't you decalred the second parameter(the element...) you can rollback if you like to.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('div.testdiv a[href^=/link3').parents();
```

Comment: This will select the `a` elements, not the `div`s.

Comment: And `parents` will select all the parents of the (undesired) div up to the `<body>`....